# Dim background like when displaying a dialog

Tags: android, layout, dialog, window, screen

I would like to obtain the same effect as when a modal dialog is displayed, i.e. dimmed background, can't interact with it, but to have a layout element, or more, active "on top" of the rest. For example: I tap on an icon and a panel with detailed information appears from the left, and you can do some stuff on that panel, the rest of the screen is dimmed, inactive. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: You could create a view filling up the whole screen with background colour #80000000 (50% opacity black); then position your control over it.

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a new Activity with the background set to transparent on some elements, for example:

```
<ScrollView
 android:gravity="left"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@android:color/transparent">
```

There is also an example of a TranslucentActivity in the Android API Demos:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TranslucentActivity.html

Comment: Also - if you want the background blurred, call this in your onResume():
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);

Comment: Thanks for the blurred background idea.