# Android View Brightness

Tags: android, view, android-dialogfragment, brightness

I want to obtain the same effect as a DialogFragment. In my activity i have 2 LinearLayout. One layout is visible and the other is gone. When I press a button i want to display the second LinearLayout (which is gone) and decrease brightness of the principal layout.

I tried these links but it didn't work for me.

[Brightness of view: Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430061/brightness-of-view-android)

[Dim background like when displaying a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727211/dim-background-like-when-displaying-a-dialog)

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I think the best solution is to use the Dialog object itself and inflate your second Linear Layout in it. This way you have the effect and behavior you want. Yes, you can put many things inside a dialog